# In Charging Circuit with battery detection

Tags: switches, battery-charging

The circuit is charging the battery with Vcharge and VCharge also power up the circuit operation. Battery will serve to power the circuit when main power supply VCharge cut off.

A switch is added to connect battery to the circuit with led indicator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1ksJD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The led is act as indicator to show the battery is connected to the circuit. It is operated as expected when the switch is turned on without Vcharge. However, when VCharge is applied , then the led will also light on regardless of the switch turn on or not where it is needed to charge the battery.

Is there any method to make the led light on only when the switch is turn on even when VCharge is applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any method to make the led light on only when the switch is
>   turn on even when VCharge is applied?

Use a double pole switch like this: -

[image]

Only when the switch is operated will the LED illuminate.